# Apache slow at responding

Tags: apache-2.2

I am running Apache locally on my MacBook Pro, which runs OS X Lion. Up until recently, the server has responded fine. Now, however, it seems to be slow to respond.

I made a request to visit a virtual host on my machine at 22:17:00. Apache did not start responding until 22:17:10. I checked my Apache logs and this is all there is:

`127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2012:22:17:10 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -`

There doesn't seem to be anything holding it up that I can see from the `access_log`, and there are no errors in `error_log`.

This happens every few minutes, with intervals of normal speed responses in-between. Most notably when a connection has not been made in the last couple of minutes.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Apache running what?  Static files? PHP? Ruby? Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553256/1082754

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 4):

Using chrome developer tools (ctrl-shift-I) you can get an idea exactly at what stage the browser is hanging like so;

[image]

---

Also, you can start httpd under strace to watch exactly what it is waiting for (not sure what the equivalent OS X lion commands would be...)

```
# strace -t -T -f /usr/sbin/httpd -X -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
23:19:35 execve("/usr/sbin/httpd", ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-X", "-f", "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"], [/* 29 vars */]) = 0 <0.000008>
brk(0)   
.
.
.
```

Obviously there will be quite a bit of output, but as your page is hanging for 10 seconds, you should have ample time to cut and paste the syscall that is taking 10 seconds.

---

You might want to check that HostnameLookups has been disabled in httpd.conf file;
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/core.html#hostnamelookups

When that is set to "on" httpd tried to do a DNS lookup for every incoming request, and this can be slow if your local naming is not working correctly, or are on an unreliable connection.

Comment: I just checked and it's already off, so unfortunately that isn't the problem.

Comment: it looks like dtrace is the mac OS equivalent of strace - http://www.troeger.eu/cms/?p=255

Comment: worked for me. I used the web dev tools in firefox though. same diff. I had forgotten about some dev stuff which I hadnt completed. it was taking 34 secs to load.

Answer (score 0):

It may stem from mysql connection too.
Yo can control it by taking connection string to top of your php page and add return false before connection string then test it i wheather it is ok or not .

If the problem  is due to the mysql slow connection you can solve the problem like this.:

If you closed mysql to network, I mean if you activated
bind-address="127.0.0.1" in my.ini under [mysqld].
You should also open for ip6
bind-address = ::1

```
# Change here for bind listening
bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# for ipv6
bind-address = ::1
```